# Unable to animate the icons with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, icons, font-awesome

I am trying to animate 4 icons to **simulate wifi signals** with *Javascript*, hower after the last signal is reached
the animation does not restart again.
Here is what i have tried.
I would appreciate any help and idea how to achieve this either with
CSS or Javascript.

```js
function makeSignal(){
        let wifi_icon = document.getElementById("wifi-signal");
        wifi_icon.classList.add('ri-signal-wifi-line');

        setTimeout(function() {
            wifi_icon.classList.remove('ri-signal-wifi-line');
            wifi_icon.classList.add('ri-signal-wifi-1-line');
        }, 500);

        setTimeout(function() {
            wifi_icon.classList.remove('ri-signal-wifi-1-line');
            wifi_icon.classList.add('ri-signal-wifi-2-line');
        }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function(){
            wifi_icon.classList.remove('ri-signal-wifi-2-line');
            wifi_icon.classList.add('ri-signal-wifi-3-line');
        }, 1500);
}

makeSignal();
setInterval(makeSignal, 2000);
```

```css
#signal {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/remixicon@2.5.0/fonts/remixicon.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="signal">
     <i id="wifi-signal" class="ri-5x"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have no idea if this works, but it seems that in the last `setTimeout`, you use `wifi_icon.classList.add('ri-signal-wifi-3-line')` and then, at the start of the function (next loop), you never remove that class. So add something like:

```
let wifi_icon = document.getElementById("wifi-signal");
wifi_icon.classList.remove('ri-signal-wifi-3-line');
wifi_icon.classList.add('ri-signal-wifi-line');
```